# Bootstrap not work in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I cannot open my application because of this error , i tried to add `// *= require "bootstrap-responsive"` but this did not work , also i have tried to remove the code from custom and adding it into application then renaming application to `application.css.scss` , and i tried to rename custom into `custom.scss` only but i cannot find any solution that work. what i can do ?

```
Sass::SyntaxError at /
File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-responsive.
Load paths:
  Sass::Rails::Importer(/home/dexter/Desktop/Sherif/Triton/app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss)
  /home/dexter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.0.2.1/vendor/assets/stylesheets
  (in /home/dexter/Desktop/Sherif/Triton/app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss)
```

Custom.css.scss

```
// Example using 'Spruce' bootswatch
//
// First import variables
@import "bootswatch/cerulean/variables";

// Then bootstrap itself
@import "bootstrap";

// Bootstrap body padding for fixed navbar
body { padding-top: 60px; }

// Responsive styles go here in case you want them
@import "bootstrap-responsive";

// And finally bootswatch style itself
@import "bootswatch/cerulean/bootswatch";

....
```

Application.css

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require jquery.ui.all
 *= require bootstrap-datepicker
 *= require bootstrap-timepicker
 *= require bootstrap_form
 *= require style-metro
 *= require login
 *= require font
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

Gemfile ( i tried to move bootstrap out of assets group but i did not solve the error also)

```
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', '3.2.4'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.0.2.0'
...


end
```

My error just happened after i pushing my project to github and then cloning it again to use it

Comment: Are you sure you have bootstrap-responsive file?

Comment: i dont have it, and the version before pushing to git was working without problems

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Bootstrap-responsive has been removed since Bootstrap 3.0.

3.0 is mobile first design, and responsiveness is native now.

Remove that require statement, no need now.

*Addition*

Dexter(OP) finally solved the problem by going back to 2.3. Though the case is rare, I think two lessons can be learned:

1. Always add version to critical gems.
2. Always use `bundle install` or `bundle`(default to install). Only use `bundle update` when it's really necessary and you are fully prepared.

Comment: when i remove it , it raises an error because of @import "bootstrap" ,  removing this also telling me undefined mixin box-shadow, any help with this?

Comment: If the swatch is for 2.3, I'm afraid it can no longer be used on 3.0 as all variable names have been changed. You can check details here: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#migration

Comment: okay , what can i do in order to make the swatch working again using 2.3 ? because everything was working normally before pushing to github

Comment: I don't understand why you have `bootstrap-sass` gem at 3.0.2.0 specifically but you were using bootstrap 2 before? I guess you havn't specify version before, but got it updated in a bundle task? If so, you can assign bootstrap-sass at 2.3.2.0 and `bundle install`, then you'll be using Bootstrap 2.

Comment: okay i have set `bootstrap-sass '2.3.2.0'` > `bundle install` > `rake tmp:clear` , could you add this to your answer in case you are using bootstrap 2.3 so it can help anyone else :)

Comment: Dexter, nice your problem solved :) I have updated the answer trying to help someone with similar cases.